# dotnet ef command showing below error in mac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Executing `dotnet ef` command showing below error in mac

```
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/preetham.p-m/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: x64
App host version: 7.0.5
.NET location: Not found
```

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=osx.13-x64&apphost_version=7.0.5

I have installed dotnet 6 in my machine
dotnet --info

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.408
 Commit:    0c3669d367

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  13.4
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.13-arm64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.16
  Architecture: arm64
  Commit:       1e620a42e7

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

`dotnet ef` command to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet-ef` is the package name. The command is `dotnet ef` with a space. You don't mention that you have installed the EF Core tools. Also the version of EF tools needs to match the SDK version.

You need to install EF Core tools by running:

```bash
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

or installing a specific version with:

```bash
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.16
```

See [Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet)

Comment: **dotnet-ef** in already installed.

Comment: I don't see that dotnet ef has a --version option. What is the output of dotnet ef without any options?

Comment: Same as above message


You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/preetham.p-m/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: x64
App host version: 7.0.5
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=osx.13-x64&apphost_version=7.0.5

Comment: The tools are version 7.0.5 and the SDK version is 6.0.408. Try removing ef tools and reinstall them with version 6. "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.16" or install SDK version 7.

Comment: Previosly i had installed 6.0.0 now by updating to 6.0.16 it is working fine. Thank you @nikstra